# Doxygen - how to hide variable from documentation

Tags: doxygen

I have a safety code which requires a variable and a copy of it. 
I want to to hide the shadow redudant variable from the generated Doxygen docs, for instance, here a pseudo code:

```
uint16 Variable_1;   //!< This variable I want to show up in the docs
uint16 Variable_2;   // This one I don't want to show in the docs.
```

I could use conditional documenting (\cond) however, I need to marks or other approach per variable. As there are too much variables and they are spread in the code, oone mark per variable would be great!

If I uncheck the option "all entities" then all my local functions are hidden.

How do I hide only variables I want, like marking only "Variable_2"?

Comment: I just edited the post. It is not duplicated because I am not interested in blocks to exclude variables. I need to exclude line by line.

Comment: Still a duplicate. Possibilities \cond, not documenting (just // comment no //!), EXCLUDE_SYMBOL (can be with *, asterisk). For the copy variable there will probably be naming conventions in respect to pre / post string (and not just a higher number) and thus with EXCLUDE_SYMBOL should be possible/

Comment: Removed my duplicate comment at least for the link I cited.  I see where your request distinguishes it self.

Comment: @albert please, provide a sample code for the Variable_2 showing how to implement your suggestion. It is unclear to me yet.

Comment: I think it is better that you show what you tried.

Comment: @albert, I think I described it already, I tried several stuff but none related to not doxygen a line worked. :(

Comment: Show what you tried an d which direction you want to / can go, as written before there ae a number of possibilities and seen the limited information it is hard to decide which way to go. The solution depicted in your question already gives a possibility. When all variables have a name ending with _2: EXCLUDE_SYMBOLS=*_2.

Comment: @albert, I am not able to upload the code due to confidentiality. I attempted so many stuff that didn't work then I grouped variables. I took me long time to do so but it solved. Next time, I will try your suggestion about EXCLUDE_SYMBOLS and define variable name accordingly. This solution is feasible, since I have mirroed variables in RAM and they follow pattern, something like:  

uint16 MyVar_1;
uint16 Mirror_MyVar_1;

Thanks!

Comment: @Marcelo did you try the `@private` command?